Product of normal $p$-nilpotent subgroups
This quetion is about the definition of p-Fitting subgroup of a group $G$.
A finite group $G$ is called $p$-nilpotent, if it has a normal subgroup $N$, such that $G=NP$, $N\cap P=1$ ($P$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup of G).
My question is if $M$ and $N$ are normal $p$-nilpotent subgroups of $G$, then whether $MN$ is a $p$-nilpotent subgroup of $G$ or not?
If the answer is yes, then we can define a subgroup $F_p(G)$ of $G$ as the product of all normal p-nilpotent subgroups of $G$, and then we call $F_p(G)$ p-Fitting subgroup of $G$.

What is $MN$? Is it a group? (Consider for instance two non-commuting transpositions in a symmetric group, then $M$, $N$ to be the groups of order two generated by the one, respectively the other transposition. What is $MN$ in this simple case? The group generated by $M,N$, or the set of products $mn$ with $m\in M$, $n\in N$... ?!)

@dan_fulea He says $M$ and $N$ are normal, so $MN$ is a (normal) subgroup of $G$.

Hint: the $p$-complement of  $M$ is characteristic in $M$, so normal in $G$. So look at the product of the $p$-complements.

@ancientmathematician Yes! I was just wanting to see "more", as it comes the question is isolated, has no content, no minimal effort (for instance in a toy example) to see what happens...

It is true and I have a proof for you. Hope we can reopen the post.
